# how to compress payload packet UDP with lz4?

Tags: c++, omnet++, lz4

I was confused and almost desperate how to compress the payload and how to enter parameters into the lz4
Please help me
[note: i use omnet 5.4.1 with inet 4.x]

```
long msgByteLength= *messageLengthPar;
Packet *pk = new Packet(msgName);
const auto& payload = makeShared<ApplicationPacket>();
payload->setChunkLength(B(msgByteLength));
payload->setSequenceNumber(numSent);
pk->insertAtBack(payload);`
```

Comment: Perhaps lines 40-59 of this example program will help you:  https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/dev/examples/simple_buffer.c

Comment: thank you very much